# Store data in Json, update with new data and retrieve a single key (index key and needs to be update for each update)

Tags: python, arrays, json, list, dictionary

What I want to do is:
Store data in JSON file then once is stored and the program ends

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I want to be able to run the program for the second time and store in the same JSON file new data,  retrieving the index (from the first bunch of data that I stored) adding +1 to create a new number, and store the second bunch of data in the same file and so on

this is my code:

```
from datetime import*
import json

#values and while loop to create the batch number

today=date.today()

componentNumber=int(input("Please input a number: "))
nCompWhile=componentNumber

types=(input("Please input types: "))

sizemodel=(input("Please input a size model: "))



index = 1
serialNList=[]

while nCompWhile > 0:
    serialNList.append(today.strftime("%d%m%Y") +
                       "{0:04}".format(index) + " - "
                       + "{0:04}".format(nCompWhile))
    nCompWhile -= 1

i = 0
compStatus = []
for element in serialNList:
    compStatus.append(serialNList[i] + " : unfinished work")
    i += 1

#The def should compare the the index with the index stored before 

def uniqueBatchN(x):
    if x == data["batch number"]:
        x = today.strftime("%d%m%Y") + "{0:04}".format(index+1)
        return x
    else:
        x= today.strftime("%d%m%Y")+ "{0:04}".format(index)
        return x

x= today.strftime("%d%m%Y")+ "{0:04}".format(index)

data={}

data["record"]=[]
data["record"].append({
    "batch number":x,
    "component type": types,
    "component size/fitment type": sizemodel,
    "components number in batch": str(componentNumber),
    "serial sumbers": str(serialNList[::-1]),
    "component status": str(compStatus[::-1]),
})
with open('data.json','w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data,outfile)

with open('data.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for p in data['record']:
        print("Batch Number: "+ p["batch number"])
        print("Component Type: "+ p["component type"])
        print("Component size/fitment type: "+ p["component size/fitment type"])
        print("Number of components in batch: "+p["components number in batch"])
        print("Serial Numbers: "+ p["serial sumbers"])
        print("Component status: "+ p["component status"])
```

But the result is that it continues to update the JSON file deleting the value of the key stored before and naturally at the same the index is not updated with the new "batch number"
This is the output:

```
Please input a number: 3
Please input types: type
Please input a size model: mode
Batch Number: 170220180001
Component Type: type
Component size/fitment type: mode
Number of components in batch: 3
Serial Numbers: ['170220180001 - 0001', '170220180001 - 0002', '170220180001 - 0003']
Component status: ['170220180001 - 0001 : unfinished work', '170220180001 - 0002 : unfinished work', '170220180001 - 0003 : unfinished work']
```

Second output:

```
Please input a number: 2
Please input types: mode
Please input a size model: type
Batch Number: 170220180001
Component Type: mode
Component size/fitment type: type
Number of components in batch: 2
Serial Numbers: ['170220180001 - 0001', '170220180001 - 0002']
Component status: ['170220180001 - 0001 : unfinished work', '170220180001 - 0002 : unfinished work']
```

Answer (score 0):

To anwser your question directly, this bit:

```
with open('data.json','w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data,outfile)
```

is opening the file in 'write' mode, i.e. any input to the file will overwrite whatever content could be in the file, hence why you're only ever finding the latest record after each run.

What you want is opening the file in 'append' mode:

```
with open('data.json','a') as outfile:
    json.dump(data,outfile)
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Now bear in mind that your code has more problems, the least not being that appending json objects outside of list brackets (and without a comma separator) results in invalid json, thus crashing your `json.load`.

Comment: Antoine M. can you please be more specific?

Comment: If you mean with regard to my last paragraph, you are writing json objects one after another like this {"key": "value"}{"key": "value"}. This break when you try to load them using json.load as they need to be structured in a list like this: [{"key": "value"}, {"key": "value"}]